# Apache Pig Input Path error using Cloudera quick-start vm and pig shell

Tags: java, hadoop, path, apache-pig

I tried to run the the following pig commands for a yelp assignment:

```
-- *******   PIG LATIN SCRIPT for Yelp Assignmet ******************

-- 0. get function defined for CSV loader

register /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;

define CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();



-- The data-fu jar file has a CSVLoader with more options, like reading multiline records,

--  but for this assignment we don't need it, so the next line is commented out

-- register /home/cloudera/incubator-datafu/datafu-pig/build/libs/datafu-pig-incubating-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;

-- 1 load data

Y      = LOAD '/usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv' USING CSVLoader() AS(business_id:chararray,cool,date,funny,id,stars:int,text:chararray,type,useful:int,user_id,name,full_address,latitude,longitude,neighborhoods,open,review_count,state);

Y_good = FILTER Y BY (useful is not null and stars is not null);

--2 Find max useful

Y_all = GROUP Y_good ALL;

Umax  = FOREACH Y_all GENERATE MAX(Y_good.useful);

DUMP Umax
```

Unfortunately, I get the following Error:

> Failed!
>
> Failed Jobs: JobId    Alias   Feature Message Outputs
>   job_1455222366557_0010    Umax,Y,Y_all,Y_good GROUP_BY,COMBINER   Message:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118:
>   Input path does not exist:
>   hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:597)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:614)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:492)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1306)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1303)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1303)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:191)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:270)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input
>   path does not exist:
>   hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
>     ... 18 more
>     hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/temp864992621/tmp897146964,
>
> Input(s): Failed to read data from
>   "/usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv"
>
> Output(s): Failed to produce result in
>   "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/temp864992621/tmp897146964"
>
> Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable
>   Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_1455222366557_0010
>
> 2016-02-15 06:22:16,643 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Failed! 2016-02-15 06:22:16,686 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator
>   for alias Umax Details at logfile:
>   /home/cloudera/pig_1455546020789.log

I have checked the the path to the file here (see image below):

[image]

It seems it resembles the same path seen in the error:

> hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv

So, I do not know how else to resolve it! Could there be something else I am not seeing? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload your csv into hdfs (using hadoop dfs -put ) and give the path in load command (load '{hdfs path of csv file}' )

Answer (score 0):

The system (whatever it means) expects the path of the file to be loaded to start  under /user/cloudera/

So, the way out is to put the file somewhere there, like this, for example:

hdfs dfs -put /usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv /user/cloudera/pigin

and show the following path in the Load:

Y = LOAD '**pigin/index_data.cs**v' USING CSVLoader() AS(business_id:chararray,cool,date,funny,id,stars:int,text:chararray,type,useful:int,user_id,name,full_address,latitude,longitude,neighborhoods,open,review_count,state);